# Tile file number in subfolder doesn't equal to the subfolder number in the folder exported from MapTiler engine

Tags: tiles, maptiler, tiling-scheme

From the document from MapTiler (https://documentation.maptiler.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405435316369-Tiling-scheme-in-Folder-output),

> The map tiles are structured into folders, and the final tile image is a file within one of these folders. Each zoom level is a folder, each column is a subfolder, and each tile in that column is a file.

That means, the files in column folder should equals to the number of subfolder.
For example, in zoom 3, there should be 8 subfolder, and in each subfolder, there should be 8 files.

However, that is not true from my export result.
Following image is the subfolders in zoom 3 folder. There are 8 subfolders as expected.

[image]

Following image is what in subfolder 0. There are only 5 iamges. But there should be 8 images.

[image]

Following image is what in subfolder 4. There are only 5 images. But there should be 8 images.

[image]

Does anyone know why?